# PHP Timestamp Changes before midnight to next day

Tags: php, wordpress, timestamp

I've tried different ways to get my timestamp to change at midnight to the next day, but I haven't had any luck. I am using Wordpress, and changed the default location to Mountain Time. I figured that these two would communicate together but I haven't had any luck.

```
<?php current_time(timestamp);   echo date('l, F jS Y'); ?>

<?php ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Denver');
echo date('l, F jS Y'); ?>
```

The first one I am trying now, and the second snippet is one I was using prior.

Its hard to debug this, since I have to wait until the night to see if the date changes early to the next day. Not optimal. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What do you mean by early. 10 minutes or 6 hours?

Comment: first of all get your current default timezone with this function [date_default_timezone_get()](http://ir2.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) , I think your current timezone is **America/Denver**

Comment: What do you mean by *"get my timestamp to change at midnight to the next day"* ? When it's 12 PM the time will start to be in the next day normally. Can you explain more what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: As ttrasn suggested, first get your current time zone, then make sure that is not overwritten by other configuration files.
This set timezone for the current script: date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
NOTE: Mountain .......... America/Denver; Mountain no DST ... America/Phoenix

Comment: I meant that the date changes about 6 hours prior to midnight....so Im trying to get it accurately to change at midnight for the Mountain Time Zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't have the timezone well configured in your server. Just output the full date and time, you don't have to wait for midnight to get the difference between the right and wrong hour.

Regarding time and timezone in php you have to know two facts:

- timestamps are always GMT, **NOT depending on the timezone**
- date output is a timestamp formatted, **depending on the timezone**

Knowing this you can easily debug your program.

```
<?php 

echo date('r').PHP_EOL; 
// timezone not configured
// Wed, 02 Jan 2019 16:11:36 +0000
echo date('U').PHP_EOL; 
// 1546445496
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Denver');
echo date('r').PHP_EOL;
// Wed, 02 Jan 2019 09:11:36 -0700
echo date('U').PHP_EOL; 
// 1546445496 , same as above
```

From this point you have many solutions, I recommend the following two:

- Put this in your php.ini file:

  ```
   date.timezone="America/Denver"
  ```
- If you cannot edit the php.ini, use the DateTime object to convert it manually.

  ```
   $d = new DateTime();
   $d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
   echo $d->format('r').PHP_EOL;
   // Wed, 02 Jan 2019 09:11:36 -0700
  ```

Comment: Thank you for this! One question...I added the DateTime object and the time is about 6 hours ahead. It looks like its rendering Universal time and not local time. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Got it to work with the second snippet you provided. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TractionW check also that the server is providing a valid Universal time value, the last value of the time formatted is the time offset that depends on the local time (09:11:36 **-0700**)

Answer (score 0):

> Function that return exact timezone difference along with update time
>   including DayLight Saving. Feel free to contact for further
>   assistance.

```
/*
 * @function minusonesecond return timezone
 * @param integer $timezonedifference       optional
 * @return string time
 * @Comment Get User TimeZone Difference
 */
public function minusonesecond($timezonedifference=""){
    $i=0;
    $time = explode(":", $timezonedifference);
    if($time[0]<0){$sign=-1; }else {$sign =1;}
    foreach ($time as $endtmp){
        $endtmp = $sign*$endtmp;
        if($i>0){
            $tmp[$i] = (($endtmp*1==0) ?  59: ($endtmp-1));
        } else $tmp[$i] = ($endtmp-1);
        $i++;
    }
    $ret = ($sign)* $tmp[0].":".(($tmp[1]>9)?$tmp[1]:"0$tmp[1]").":".(($tmp[2]>9)?$tmp[2]:"0$tmp[2]");
    return $ret ;
}

/**
 * @function getusertimezonedifference return timezone difference with UTC
 * @param integer $timezonedifference       optional
 * @return string time
 * @Comment Get User TimeZone Difference
 */
public function getusertimezonedifference($user_id = "", $changetoUTC=false, $flg_array=false)
{
    $user = $this->User->find("first", array("conditions" => array("User.user_id" => $user_id)));
    $timezone = $user["Timezone"]["timezone_name"];
    $dayLightFlag = false;
    $system_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $local_timezone = "UTC";
    date_default_timezone_set($local_timezone);
    $local = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $gmt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $required = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set($system_timezone);
    $diff1 = (strtotime($gmt) - strtotime($local));
    $diff2 = (strtotime($required) - strtotime($gmt));
    if($changetoUTC) {$diff2 =  (-1*$diff2);}
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($diff2 / (60 * 60));
    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $diff2 % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    //create string HH:MM:SS
    $ret = $hours.":".(($minutes>9)?$minutes:"0$minutes").":".(($seconds>9)?$seconds:"0$seconds");
    if($flg_array){$ret = array($hours, (($minutes>9)?$minutes:"0$minutes"), ($seconds>9)?$seconds:"0$seconds");}
    return ($ret);
}

/**
 * @function getPSTtimezonedifference return timezone difference with UTC AND PST
 * @param  $changetoUTC       optional
 * @param $flg_array       optional
 * @return string time
 * @Comment Get User TimeZone Difference
 */
public function getPSTtimezonedifference($changetoUTC=false, $flg_array=false)
{
    $timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";
    $dayLightFlag = false;
    $system_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $local_timezone  = "UTC";
    date_default_timezone_set($local_timezone);
    $local = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $gmt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $required = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set($system_timezone);
    $diff1 = (strtotime($gmt) - strtotime($local));
    $diff2 = (strtotime($required) - strtotime($gmt));
    if($changetoUTC) {$diff2 =  (-1*$diff2);}
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($diff2 / (60 * 60));
    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $diff2 % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    //create string HH:MM:SS
    $ret = $hours.":".(($minutes>9)?$minutes:"0$minutes").":".(($seconds>9)?$seconds:"0$seconds");
    if($flg_array){$ret = array($hours, (($minutes>9)?$minutes:"0$minutes"), ($seconds>9)?$seconds:"0$seconds");}
    return ($ret);
}
```